# "No visible @interface" error with method

Tags: objective-c, interface

CJSHWork as a class is defined in CJSHWork.h and CJSHWork.m. In CJSHWork.h I have:

```
@interface CJSHWork : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *url;

-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)name filename:(NSString *)title content:(NSString *)url;

@end
```

In CJSHWork.m I have:

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString *)name title:(NSString *)title content:(NSString *)url
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _name = name;
        _title = title;
        _url = url;
    }
}
```

And I have, in CJSHDataController.m,

```
import "CJSHWork.h"
```

...

```
CJSHWork *work = [[CJSHWork alloc] initWithName:@"" title:allWorks[i][1] url:url];
```

This gets the error "**No visible @interface for CJSHWork declares the selector initWithName title url**".

What is going on here, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method name is initWithName:title:content: not initWithName:title:url:

Comment: It's worse than that. The method is declared with one name in the .h file and implemented with a different name in the .m in addition to calling it with yet a 3rd name.

Comment: Thank you both. I made an (obviously incomplete) switch in variable names.